# Can I use a shell or python script to execute commands in a chroot?

Tags: arch-linux, chroot

I need: to make a shellscript which can chroot into a linux environment and run a command there.
I am using: arch-chroot (on the  arch linux livecd)

Comment: `chroot /targetdir command`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should issue the command:

```
 chroot /chroot_dir /bin/bash -c "su - -c ./yourscript.sh"
```